# No notifications with Facebook messenger after upgrading to 4.4

Tags: notifications, facebook-messenger

I have a Galaxy S2 that is rooted and I recently upgraded to Kitkat 4.4.

After doing so, I've noticed that Facebook Messenger does not alert me when a new message comes in. It would before the upgrade, and I restored it from backup, so I assume it's the same program.

I have gone through the interface to ensure that notifications are set to be on. I have also looked in the app manager and made sure that notifications are enabled for this app.

I do seem to be getting notifications with Gmail when I get a new mail, but I'm not sure of other programs are affected.

How do I ensure that Facebook Messenger notifications are operating as they should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't yet updated you should. it might be the problem that it isen't yet compattable with your OS. if that is not the case, reinstal the app so it is fresh and clean.